# what this var guess = require('myModule1')('myMmodule2'); do?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I found this in a code and do not know which instance receives.

```
var guess = require ('myModule1') ('myMmodule2')
```

Comment: Check the docs/implementation of `myModule1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `myModule1` exports a function which is then called with the argument `myMmodule2`.

Comment: 0k. I found this on myModule1:

Comment: `function Module1 = function (otherModule){
  // do things whith otherModule
  return this;
}
exports.myModule = function(otherModule){
  return new Module1(otherModule);
}`